# Load Testing using JMeter with NATS.io

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, nats.io

How could I use JMeter in [NATS](https://nats.io) services?

I found some articles supporting about how to use JMeter for some messaging brokers like RabbitMQ. However, I didn't find any guidelines to use the JMeter in NATS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JMeter doesn't support the [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by the system under test the next step will be finding a client library for this protocol to mimic real life user or application. For NATS it would be [NATS - Java Client](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.java)

Download the library and its transitive dependencies if any, drop the jar(s) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and you should be able to use the library API from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

You might also consider [developing your own plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) for JMeter.